# Problem with typescript in middleware for default returns in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I have a middleware that standardizes the responses. Here is the code:

> responses.js

```js
const TYPE_JSON = 'application/json';
const STATUS_CODE_OK = 200;
const STATUS_CODE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY = 201;
const STATUS_CODE_BAD_REQUEST = 400;
const STATUS_CODE_UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
const STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND = 404;
const STATUS_CODE_SERVER_ERROR = 500;

const jsonOK = function (data, message) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_OK;

    message = message ? message : 'Successful request.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_OK);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
};

const jsonCreated = function (data, message) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;

    message = message ? message : 'Created successfully.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
}

const jsonBadRequest = function (data, message) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_BAD_REQUEST;

    message = message ? message : 'Bad request.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_BAD_REQUEST);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
};

const jsonNotFound = function (data, message) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND;

    message = message ? message : 'Not found.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
};

const response = (req, res, next) => {
    res.jsonOK = jsonOK;
    res.jsonCreated = jsonCreated;
    res.jsonBadRequest = jsonBadRequest;

    next();
};

module.exports = response;
```

So in my controllers, I call it like this:

```js
router.get('/', (request, response) => {
   return response.jsonOK();
})
```

But recently I started to migrate my project to typescript, so...

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

const TYPE_JSON = 'application/json';
const STATUS_CODE_OK = 200;
const STATUS_CODE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY = 201;
const STATUS_CODE_BAD_REQUEST = 400;
const STATUS_CODE_UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
const STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND = 404;
const STATUS_CODE_SERVER_ERROR = 500;

const jsonOK = function (data: any, message: string) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_OK;

    message = message ? message : 'Successful request.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_OK);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
};

const jsonCreated = function (data: any, message: string) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;

    message = message ? message : 'Created successfully.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
}

const jsonBadRequest = function (data: any, message: string) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_BAD_REQUEST;

    message = message ? message : 'Bad request.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_BAD_REQUEST);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
};

const jsonNotFound = function (data: any, message: string) {
    const status = STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND;

    message = message ? message : 'Not found.';

    this.status(STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND);
    this.type(TYPE_JSON);

    return this.json({ message, data, status: status });
};

const response = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.jsonOK = jsonOK;
    res.jsonCreated = jsonCreated;
    res.jsonBadRequest = jsonBadRequest;

    next();
};

module.exports = response;
```

But it complains about a lot of things like:

- this. has an implicit type any
- jsonOK, jsonCreated, jsonBadRequest not found in type Response

So nothing is working anymore, how can i fix this?

Comment: You aren't specifying a return value in your TypeScript for your methods `jsonCreated()`, `jsonBadRequest()`, etc..., but you are returning a value with statements like `return this.json({ message, data, status: status });`.  The two need to match.  Or, if you don't actually need a return value from those, then remove `return` from `return this.json(...)` and don't specify any return value.

Comment: FYI, though it isn't documented, `res.json()` probably just returns `res` so you could specify a `Response` object as the return value and if you look at the [Express source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js) that does appear to be what it returns.

Comment: I didn't understand very well the solution @jfriend00.